# Twilio ConversationAPI get an existing conversation between a user and participant

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I am looking for a way to pass in the ID of two users (a user and participant?), and retrieve the messages from that conversation. Is there a way through the conversations API to do this? I have been trying a few different ways but have not found a solution. Am I missing something right in front of me?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To [list the messages from a conversation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-message-resource#list-all-conversation-messages), you need that conversation's SID. You can't just provide the user's IDs. When you create a conversation and add the users in the first place, you should store the conversation SID so that you can look things up again in the future.

Comment: That didn't answer the question.

Comment: I do not know of a way to get the messages of a conversation from just the IDs of the participants. I would suggest you re-architect so that you can store the conversation SID and use that.